# If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple Lie algebra then $\mathfrak{g}=D\mathfrak{g}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, lie-algebras

I want to show that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple Lie algebra (over $\mathbb{C}$), then $D\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}$, and I have a couple of questions about my proof.

First, observe that $D\mathfrak{g}$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$, and the killing form $B(X,Y)=\text{tr}(ad(X)ad(Y))$ for $X,Y\in \mathfrak{g}$ is non-degenerate. Then if we can show that $\mathfrak{g}=D\mathfrak{g}\oplus D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}$ where
$$D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}=\{X\in \mathfrak{g}:B(X,Y)=0\text{ for all } Y\in D\mathfrak{g}\}$$
and that $D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}=0$, then we will have $\mathfrak{g}=D\mathfrak{g}$.

$(1)$ Let's show that $\mathfrak{g}=D\mathfrak{g}\oplus D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}$. First, we see that $D\mathfrak{g}+ D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}\subset\mathfrak{g}$. Also, we know that $D\mathfrak{g}\cap D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}=0$ as a solvable ideal in a semisimple Lie algebra. So, $D\mathfrak{g}\oplus D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}\subset\mathfrak{g}$. **How can I show that $\dim(D\mathfrak{g}\oplus D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp})=\dim\mathfrak{g}$?**

$(2)$ Let's show that $D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}=0$. It can be shown by using the following property of the killing form $B(X,Y)$
$$B(X,[Y,Z])=B([X,Y],Z)$$
for all $X,Y,Z\in\mathfrak{g}.$ Indeed, if we take $X\in D\mathfrak{g}^{\perp}$, then $B(X,[Y,Z])=0$ for all $[Y,Z]\in D\mathfrak{g}$ where the choice of $Y$ and $Z$ is arbitrary. So, we have $B([X,Y],Z)=0$ for all $Z\in\mathfrak{g}$ i.e. $[X,Y]=0$ for all $Y\in\mathfrak{g}$. So, $X$ must be zero as he commutes with all elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ i.e. the $\text{span}(X)$ is one-dimensional abelian ideal.

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have that $D\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}$.

**Question:** Is there another/shorter way to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another proof. It uses that a semisimple Lie algebra is the direct sum of simple ideals
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{s}_1\oplus\cdots \oplus \mathfrak{s_n}.
$$
Because $\mathfrak{s}_i$ is simple and $[\mathfrak{s}_i,\mathfrak{s}_i]$ is a nonzero ideal, it follows $\mathfrak{s}_i=[\mathfrak{s}_i,\mathfrak{s}_i]$ for all $i$, and hence also $$[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]=\mathfrak{g}.$$

Comment: Slightly shorter: to say that $[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}] = \mathfrak{g}$ is to say that $\mathfrak{g}$ has trivial abelianization, and since a simple Lie algebra has trivial abelianization so does any direct sum of them.